# Saving a model with inlines in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

This seems like a very easy problem, but I really can't figure out what's going on. I have some problems understanding the saving process on the Django admin site. This is the situation, simplified as much as possible:

`models.py`

```
import uuid

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=settings.IS_DEV)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Order(BaseModel):
    [various properties and functions]


class Article(BaseModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    [various properties and functions]


class PaymentOperation(BaseModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    [various properties and functions]
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

from models import Order, Article, PaymentOperation


class BaseModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['created', 'modified']
    if not settings.IS_DEV:
        readonly_fields.append('id')


class ArticleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ['id', ...]
    readonly_fields = ['id', ...]
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    max_num = 0

    [more code]


class PaymentOperationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ['id', ...]
    readonly_fields = ['id', ...]
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    max_num = 0

    [more code]


class OrderAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = BaseModelAdmin.readonly_fields + [...]
    fieldsets = [...]
    inlines = [ArticleInline, PaymentOperationInline]

    [more code]


class ArticleAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = BaseModelAdmin.readonly_fields + [...]
    fieldsets = [...]

    [more code]
```

This is the main structure, but I'm not really sure if it's enough to generate the problem. I didn't want to clog the question with hundreds of lines of code. I'll try to be more specific if necessary.

Some fields in the Order and Article models are editable, while all fields in the PaymentOperation model are read-only.

If I edit an Article from its admin page, it works perfectly. If, on the other hand, I try to edit an Order, and then save it, the page behaves strangely. The order is not saved, and an error message appears on top of the page, saying "Please correct the errors below." All the fields, both editable and read-only, remain unchanged. The two inlines at the bottom of the page are in a worse state. All read-only fields are reset to the default value, if available, or nulled, and all IDs are different. Editable fields of the article inline remain the same. It looks to me like the page is trying to create new entries, instead of editing the old ones.

I tried commenting out the inlines in the `OrderAdmin` declaration one at a time, but with no effect. Commenting out both lets me save the order correctly.

I also tried adding a `save_model` and `save_formset` to `OrderAdmin`, but whatever the error is, it's produced before these functions are called. The shell where I run `python manage.py runserver` doesn't even show any error message.

There are many other models in `models.py` and in `admin.py`, and none of them has the same problem. Some of these models even have their own inlines.

I'm really puzzled. I'm trying to understand the difference between the part of the code shown above and the rest, but I can't find it. I know the saving process worked before I added the payment operation a few days ago, and I'm almost certain that I didn't change anything in the order and article models (I will check though, just to be sure). At this point I'm not sure I understood the saving process, or what's wrong with the code.

**Edit**: I can't find significant changes to the order and article models, as well as their admin counterparts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the whole problem is located in the `editable=settings.IS_DEV` setting for the ID of every model. I don't know exactly why, but setting `editable=False` solves the problem.

I noticed I never had this problem on the production server, only on the ones flagged as development. Fortunately being able to set a specific ID was only useful in a very limited set of cases, so I won't miss it, but I feel like I just traded a problem with a less annoying one. If someone has a better solution, I'll be happy to change my mind and recognize that as the answer to this question.